# Unity Copy Movement base off facing

Tags: unity-game-engine

Please check out the GIF to see an example,

**I want the red ball to copy green balls movement but needs to be aware of the direction difference.** Meaning if green ball moves forward 5 units and then moves left 5 units. The green ball should move forward and left but based on its own forward direction. The white line indicates the forward facing for each ball.

Below are the code to recreate the current situation as shown on the Gif. I couldn't wrap my brain around how to solve this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class CalculateMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform MyOrigin;
    [SerializeField] Transform MyPosition;
    [SerializeField] Transform CopyCat;
    [SerializeField] Transform CopyCatOrigin;

    [SerializeField] float Distance;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 rawDirection;

    private void Update()
    {
        rawDirection = (MyPosition.position - MyOrigin.position).normalized;
        Distance = Vector3.Distance(MyOrigin.position, MyPosition.position);

        if (CopyCat)
        {
            CopyCat.position = rawDirection * Distance + CopyCatOrigin.position;
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + transform.forward);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(CopyCat.position, CopyCat.position + CopyCat.forward);
    }

}
```

[image: y]

Answer (score 0):

This may not work well in EditMode. For Position:

1. Get distance between MyPosition's lastPosition and current
2. Multiply that distance by MyCopy's forward
3. Add that to MyCopy's current position.

For rotation:

1. At  start, get difference between rotations
2. Set MyCopy equal to MyPositions rotation
3. Rotate MyCopy based on the rotation difference at the start

Code:

```
public class question_61470495_unity_copy_movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform MyOrigin;
    [SerializeField] Transform MyPosition;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 MyPositionLastPos;
    [SerializeField] Transform CopyCat;
    [SerializeField] Transform CopyCatOrigin;

    [SerializeField] float Distance;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 rawDirection;
    [SerializeField] float diffRot;



    private void Start()
    {
        diffRot = Vector3.Angle(MyPosition.forward, CopyCat.forward);
        Debug.Log(diffRot);
        MyPositionLastPos = MyPosition.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        CopyCat.position += CopyCat.forward * Vector3.Distance(MyPositionLastPos, MyPosition.position);

        CopyCat.rotation = MyPosition.rotation;
        CopyCat.Rotate(Vector3.up, diffRot);


        MyPositionLastPos = MyPosition.position;
    }
}
```